# Box behind navs css

Tags: html, css, navbar

so I have this navbar in my project, and as it stands at the moment, the text changes color as you hover over it.

[jsfiddle of this here](https://jsfiddle.net/82n0rwb7/2/)

HTML:

```
<div class = "container">
    <div class = "header">
        <div class = "header-main">

        </div>

        <div class = "header-nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a class = "active" href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    padding = 0;
    margin = 0;
}

.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 940px;
}

.header-main{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dadada;
    padding: 20px 0;
}

.header-nav {
    padding: 0 0;
}

.header-nav ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.header-nav ul li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.header-nav ul li a {
    color: #737373;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: 'Novecentosanswide-DemiBold';
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.header-nav ul li a.active {
    color: #2ecc71;
}

.header-nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #3e3e3e;
}
```

What I'd like to know is how I can add a box that changes color behind (EDIT: and spans the height of the nav) when you hover over it. The best example I can find of this is [Windows 10's site](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/features)

Comment: [`background-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color) ?

Comment: Setting the background color in a:hover as well. Or isn't that your question?

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't span the height of the nav. I'll edit that in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** Set links to block elements

**2.** Add padding to the links (*not* the list items)

```
.header-nav ul li a {
    color: #737373;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: 'Novecentosanswide-DemiBold';
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: block;
    padding: 4px 8px;
}
```

**3.** Set background-color to the links

```
.header-nav ul li a.active {
    background-color: #2ecc71;
}

.header-nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #3e3e3e;
}
```

**4.** Clear `ul`

```
.header-nav ul:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
```

**5.** ???

**6.** PROFIT

https://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/82n0rwb7/9/

Maybe it looks prettier without the margin on the list items? [Like so](https://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/82n0rwb7/10/).

(I just noticed that there was an error in your fiddle's CSS. You set `margin = 0` to `*`, but the designator should be a colon not an equal sign, like so: `margin: 0`.)

Comment: I think this works best. Also, good catch on the `margin = 0` error. Didn't notice that

Answer (score 0):

```
.header-nav ul li a {
    display:block;
    padding:10px;
    color: #737373;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: 'Novecentosanswide-DemiBold';
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.header-nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background:#000;
    padding:10px;

}
```

Eidting these two style classes will do the trick i think. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take control of the element size. You can do the trick with

```
// apply hover to li instead a
.header-nav ul li:hover {
    color: #3e3e3e;
    background-color: red;
}

// remove the margins for the ul
.header-nav ul {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

// implement the margins of the ul on li but as padding instead of margin
.header-nav ul li {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/82n0rwb7/8/) example

Comment: Note that for *not* mouse based devices (think about people with disabilities) this is a bad idea. Take for instance navigating by tabbing. You won't gget the hover effect because a list item isn't selectable by default. The link is.

Answer (score 0):

Few things which you missed:

- Clearing the float
- Removing margin,bottom from ul which cause unexpected dimensions.
- Adding a padding to the link anchors.

**CSS:**:

```
* {
    padding=0;
    margin=0;
}
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 940px;
}
.header-main {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dadada;
    padding: 20px 0;
}
.header-nav {
    padding: 0 0;
}
.header-nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.header-nav ul li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.header-nav ul li a {
    color: #737373;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family:'Novecentosanswide-DemiBold';
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding:5px 10px;
}
.header-nav ul li a.active {
    color: #2ecc71;
    background-color:#BFBFBF;
}
.header-nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #3e3e3e;
    background-color:#BFBFBF;
}
.header-nav ul:after {
    clear:both;
    content:"";
    display:block;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/82n0rwb7/5/